# How does the CPU know when to hold a pipeline stage back?

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture

How does the CPU check whether or not a pipeline stage is busy so it can hold all previous stages back? That is, in an example three stage pipeline, if stage 2 is taking multiple clock cycles and stalling the pipeline, how does the CPU know not to move stage 1 forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, x86-64 makes little sense as a tag for this.  There are real ARM CPUs with 3-stage pipelines (e.g. Cortex-M), but no x86-64 CPU has ever been that short.  x86 decode is too expensive for pipelines that short, and the "x86 tax" eats up too much space/performance for simple CPUs.

---

It should be fairly obvious that any given stage can detect when it needs to *initiate* a stall.  E.g. a memory-access stage can detect a cache miss load or store-buffer full (which requires stalling the pipeline on a simple CPU without any memory-level parallelism, unlike real modern x86 which can speculatively hit-under-miss and miss-under-miss).  I think you're only asking how that information is propagated backwards.

In a pipeline that can stall<sup>1</sup>, each stage has to be prepared for the possibility that the next stage won't be ready to accept new stuff.  You only need to signal the immediately previous stage, not all previous stages.  There might be bubbles earlier in the pipeline that can close up.

The obvious implementation is a signal line from each stage to the previous stage.
 If a stage isn't ready to accept new work, it raises this signal.  On the clock edge that would normally propagate data from stage to stage, the previous stage instead holds on to its data if that signal is set.

If the pipeline was full, a stall in the last stage will result in a ripple backward in the pipeline.  (Pipeline stages that were previously empty can stop the propagation: they can still accept new work this cycle even if the next stage can't take any work from them.)  This backward propagation can start earlier than the clock edge, like as soon as a late stage detects that it's going to need to stall.

In practice the latches that buffer data between stages may absorb some of this ripple latency and take it off the critical path.  Like maybe data can always get buffered by the latch at the boundary between stages, but if that signal was raised then the latch just holds onto it until later?

IDK how deep you wanted to go into digital logic / gate design.  The high-level picture is just that each stage can signal the previous stage that it isn't ready to accept new work this cycle.  And this signal has to propagate backwards somehow.

---

**Footnote 1**: Not all pipelines are capable of stalling.  e.g. a fully-pipelined integer multiply execution unit doesn't have any need for flow-control.  It can always accept a new input every cycle, no matter what.

But yes, a full CPU pipeline generally has to be able to stall for memory at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the level of depth is sufficient! I used those tags because I was interested in how it worked under those architectures - the example I used was only to try and clarify what I'm asking, rather than to accurately represent an x86(-64) pipeline.

Comment: @VortixDev: modern x86 CPUs have queues between pipeline stages to absorb bubbles.  (Since Pentium M or Core 2 or so.  e.g. see https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ and Agner Fog's uarch guide: https://agner.org/optimize/).  That decouples stages so stall ripples maybe don't have to propagate back through multiple stages, I'm not sure of the low-level details of things within one clock cycle.  They're also superscalar and out-of-order execution, although the front-end is still in-order.  Anyway, the high-level mental model of signalling the previous stage doesn't change.